# Docker on Heroku, dependencies not saved in image?

Tags: docker, heroku, julia

I have a Dockerfile that installs Julia and some dependencies, then call a script.
The 1st line of the script is "using JSServe" which should be installed.

```
# Runs ubuntu commands 
FROM ubuntu

# Install wget and other
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y tar

# Downloads and install julia 
ENV JULIA_NAME "julia-1.9.0-beta2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
RUN wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.9/${JULIA_NAME} && \
    tar -xvzf ${JULIA_NAME} && \
    mv julia-1.9.0-beta2 /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/julia-1.9.0-beta2/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia && \
    rm ${JULIA_NAME}

# Copy files
COPY Project.toml ./Project.toml 
COPY JSServe_app.jl ./JSServe_app.jl

# Install deps
RUN julia --project -e "import Pkg; Pkg.instantiate(); Pkg.precompile()"

# Run apps
CMD julia --project -e 'include("JSServe_app.jl")'
```

This works perfectly locally.
But on a remote server (Heroku), I get the following error:

```
Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c julia\ -e\ \'include\(\"JSServe_app.jl\"\)\'` 
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package JSServe not found in current path.
```

I don't understand why... JSServe should be installed - Docker build does work locally.
All files can be seen on GitHub https://github.com/AlexisRenchon/app-wglmakie-fig

I tried to install the dependencies in my Docker image, it worked locally, but not on the Heroku remote server.

EDIT:
looks like the problem is packages installed are removed somehow...

```
2023-01-31T14:38:11.444805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c julia\ --project\=.\ -e\ \"import\ Pkg\;\ Pkg.status\(\)\"`
2023-01-31T14:38:13.572537+00:00 app[web.1]:   Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
2023-01-31T14:38:17.410042+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2023-01-31T14:38:17.466348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-01-31T14:38:17.176302+00:00 app[web.1]: Status `~/Project.toml`
2023-01-31T14:38:17.212226+00:00 app[web.1]: → [824d6782] JSServe v2.1.0
2023-01-31T14:38:17.212346+00:00 app[web.1]: → [276b4fcb] WGLMakie v0.8.6
2023-01-31T14:38:17.212445+00:00 app[web.1]: Info Packages marked with → are not downloaded, use `instantiate` to download
```

Comment: can you show the content of Project.toml?

Comment: https://github.com/AlexisRenchon/app-wglmakie-fig/blob/master/Project.toml

Comment: see my answer, `--project` doesn't do anything, you need `--project=.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `--project=.`, notice the `=.`

Comment: I tried, but got the same error:
`Step 7/8 : RUN julia --project=. -e "import Pkg; Pkg.instantiate(); Pkg.precompile()"`
this installs the deps...
`Removing intermediate container 398ee8e4fe22
 ---> f5f883bd0d0a
Step 8/8 : CMD julia --project=. -e 'include("JSServe_app.jl")'
 ---> Running in f5ed2bbe0bdc
Removing intermediate container f5ed2bbe0bdc
`
is it a problem that Docker removes intermediate container?
error is still the same `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package JSServe [824d6782-a2ef-11e9-3a09-e5662e0c26f9] is required but does not seem to be installed`

Comment: yeah, the container is removing intermediate files between steps, you want to persistify it by doing multiple Julia things inside the same `RUN`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it to work:

```
# Runs ubuntu commands 
FROM ubuntu

# Install wget and other
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y tar

# Downloads and install julia 
ENV JULIA_NAME "julia-1.9.0-beta2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
RUN wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.9/${JULIA_NAME} && \
    tar -xvzf ${JULIA_NAME} && \
    mv julia-1.9.0-beta2 /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/julia-1.9.0-beta2/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia && \
    rm ${JULIA_NAME}

ENV mainpath ./
RUN mkdir -p ${mainpath}

USER ${NB_USER}

ENV USER_HOME_DIR /home/${NB_USER}
ENV JULIA_PROJECT ${USER_HOME_DIR}
ENV JULIA_DEPOT_PATH ${USER_HOME_DIR}/.julia

# Copy files
COPY Project.toml ${mainpath}/Project.toml 
COPY JSServe_app.jl ${mainpath}/JSServe_app.jl

# Install deps
RUN julia --project=${mainpath} -e "import Pkg; Pkg.instantiate(); Pkg.precompile()"

# Run apps
CMD julia --project=${mainpath} -e 'include("JSServe_app.jl")'
```